# MySQL conditional filter element from json array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, conditional-statements

Have a json array type column in MySQL, and trying to conditionally filter out some elements form the array. Here is the example:

> ### Original json array
>
> [
>    {"name": "Atencion a Clientes", "number": "*111"},
>    {"name": "Atn Ciudadana", "number": "066"}, 
>    {"name": "Atn Ctes Intl", "number": "+525525813300"}, 
>    {"name": "Bomberos", "number": "116"},
>    {"name": "Chelo", "number": "993-120-2100"}
>    ]

The desired output is like this:

> ### Desired output json array
>
> [
>    {"name": "Atn Ctes Intl", "number": "+525525813300"}, 
>    {"name": "Chelo", "number": "993-120-2100"}
>    ]

We want only keep the the elements with phone number length >= 10. Tried using the following code, which does NOT work. Is that possible to achieve this through MySQL functions ?  Thanks a lot.

> WHERE  length(replace(json_extract(phone_contacts,'$[*].number'  ) , ' ', '') ) >= 10

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting your `where` as a column of its own and check the output. If it works, you can then reference.

So

```
Select         length(replace(json_extract(phone_c ntacts,'$[*].number' ) , ' ', '') ) as my_length
```

Then reference in a `having` at the end of your query

```
Having my_length>=10
```